# How to access Linux Docker Container's TCP Port from windows 10 host

Tags: linux, docker, tcp, zeromq, docker-for-windows

I have installed Docker for windows on windows 10 . I am running Linux containers on docker. I have a python app which has ZeroMQ which has a zmq server listening on port 3000 . I want to send images from my c# app deployed on windows host to connect to the zmq app running on docker linux containers and send images through tcp using zeromq .
I am unable to access the container tcp port from windows app .
Please advise .

I tried the below:

```
C:\Windows\system32>docker run -p 3000:3000 server-zmq10 docker:
```

Error response from daemon:

```
driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint condescending_kilby
(fc383d60832ae98a5601ba62e215a4033936f74b64577ca6b14f7c47f1f27f9a): Error starting
userland proxy: mkdir /port/tcp:0.0.0.0:3000:tcp:172.17.0.2:3000: input/output error.
```

Python code:

```
context = zmq.Context()
socket = context.socket(zmq.REP)
print('Binding to port 3000')
socket.bind("tcp://127.0.0.1:3000")
```

I have done on the DockerFIle when creating the image:

```
EXPOSE 3000
```

Is there anything else which is required here ?

Comment: It sounds like you may already have a service running on your host that uses port 3000.  Try a different port for the host e.g. `-p 3001:3000` or try to determine what is already using that port.

Answer (score 0):

After exposing 3000 port is there any service running for listening?

or use -p 5000:5000 in docker run command

Comment: Hi Nishad , Below code binds the 3000 port on docker -


`context = zmq.Context()
socket = context.socket(zmq.REP)
print('Binding to port 3000')
socket.bind("tcp://127.0.0.1:3000")`